# Is Differentiation Operator bounded for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$P$ is a vector space of all polynomial functions on $C[0,1]$
$p'$ is derivative of $p$
Check whether $T : P \to P \quad T(p)= p'$ is linear bounded or not. Use $|| \; ||_{sup}$ (supremum norm) for polynomials.

T is linear so there is no problem here. I am struggling to show whether it is bounded or not.
I think it is not bounded according to the following counter example

we have to show that $||Tv|| \leq M||v|| $ for $M\geq0$

Now lets take $v=x^n$ this give $||v||=1$ and $||Lv||=n$

So there is no general constant $M$.

is it correct ?

Can someone please give any other counter example or fill the missing pieces from mine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is correct. Assume there were such $M > 0$, and choose a natural number such that $n > M$. Then, $$n = \|Tx^n\| \leq M \|x^n\| = M < n, $$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes . If T is bounded, then $\exists M\geq 0$ such that $$\forall P\in ...,  \quad||T(P)||_{\infty}\leq M||P||_{\infty},$$ Now for $P=x^n$, we have $||P||=1$, and  $||T(P)||_{\infty}=n$ $\implies$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n \leq M,$ which is absurd!